# na.locf in data.table when completing by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in which I'd like to complete a column to fill in some missing values, however I'm having some trouble filling in the other columns.

```
dt = data.table(a = c(1, 3, 5), b = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
dt[, .(a = seq(min(a), max(a), 1), b = na.locf(b))]
#    a b
# 1: 1 a
# 2: 2 b
# 3: 3 c
# 4: 4 a
# 5: 5 b
```

However looking for something more like this:

```
dt %>% 
  complete(a = seq(min(a), max(a), 1)) %>%
  mutate(b = na.locf(b))
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#       a b    
# <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 a    
# 3     3 b    
# 4     4 b    
# 5     5 c
```

where the last value is carried forward

Comment: Where does `na.locf` come from? `zoo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possible solution with only the (rolling) join capabilities of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
dt[.(min(a):max(a)), on = .(a), roll = Inf]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    a b
> 1: 1 a
> 2: 2 a
> 3: 3 b
> 4: 4 b
> 5: 5 c
> ```

On large datasets this will probably outperform every other solution.

Courtesy to @Mako212 who gave the hint by using `seq` in his answer.

---

First posted solution which works, but gives a warning:

```
dt[dt[, .(a = Reduce(":", a))], on = .(a), roll = Inf]
```

Comment: I appreciate the reminder about rolling joins, nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` recycles observations by default when you try `dt[, .(a = seq(min(a), max(a), 1))]` so it never generates any `NA` values for `na.locf` to fill. Pretty sure you need to use a join here to "complete" the cases, and then you can use `na.locf` to fill.

```
dt[dt[, .(a = min(a):max(a))], on = 'a'][, .(a, b = na.locf(b))]
```

Not sure if there's a way to skip the separate `t1` line, but this gives you the desired result.

```
   a b
1: 1 a
2: 2 a
3: 3 b
4: 4 b
5: 5 c
```

And I'll borrow @Jaap's `min/max` line to avoid creating the second table. So basically you can either use his rolling join solution, or if you want to use `na.locf` this gets the same result.